# How to start directly a individual GUI at Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, display

I would like to start an individual GUI directly at Raspberry Pi with an attached LCD display.
The GUI is programmed using the python3 library tkinter.
This should be work via a scheduled CRON job direct after booting, without the StartX GUI.
It will work via StartX, select commandline and call i.e. the Python script test.py.
But I could find any solution to activate the LCD display without StartX.
Does anyone has a simple trick?

Comment: You want to start an X11 client to display on an X11 server without starting the X11 server? I don't see how that can possibly work.

Comment: What's an *"individual GUI"* please? Presumably as opposed to multiple GUIs.

Answer (score 0):

You need a desktop manager in order for Tkinter windows to show. If you want a minimal display manager you should use openbox. I recommend this artical. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/52099/using-openbox-to-autostart-gui-application-raspberry-pi-3.

Comment: Thanks, thats the kind of hint I waited for. I'll act on it and will report